# Using "at the time": Does it need to be followed by "when"

Tags: word-usage, grammar

I have a sentence that contains the following phrase:

> ... at the time the software is needed ...

Is this grammatically correct? Do I need to phrase it in this way:

> ... at the time **when** the software is needed ...

Comment: A relativizer--a *wh-* word or *that*--may be omitted unless it designates the subject of the relative clause. *When* of course never designates the subject, because when it introduces a relative clause it "stands for" a preposition phrase. ... Note, however, that *when* cannot be omitted in other circumstances--when it does not introduce a relative clause.

Answer (score 1):

Both are fine to use. As StoneyB said

> A relativizer—a *wh-* word or *that*—may be omitted unless it designates the subject of the relative clause. *When* of course never designates the subject, because when it introduces a relative clause it "stands for" a preposition phrase. ... Note, however, that *when* cannot be omitted in other circumstances—when it does not introduce a relative clause.